# req.on('close') event not fired when cloudflare proxy is enabled for my NodeJs App deployed in GCP

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

req.on('close') event not fired when cloudflare proxy is enabled for my NodeJs App deployed in GCP. The service type is nodeport and uses ingress load balancer  ! But the event gets fired when cloudflare proxy is disabled.
Please suggest what to do ? Please consider me as a newbie..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
Please describe your question in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual task you want to accomplish, add you erroneous code snippet and what all resolutions you actually tried already to eradicate the issue
Make note to add corresponding tags and format your code before pasting here.
For more details visit StackOverflow's guidelines.

Comment: const subscriptionName = 'subscriptionNamexyz';
const timeout = 60;
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

Comment: function listenForMessages() {
  const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription(subscriptionName);
  req.on('close', () => {
            console.debug(
                `Connection closed by client before timeout`
            )
            subscription.close()
            clearTimeout(t)
            return Responder.success(
                res,
                console.debug(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`)
            )
        })

Comment: let messageCount = 0;
  const messageHandler = message => {
    console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
    console.log(`\tData: ${message.data}`);
    console.log(`\tAttributes: ${message.attributes}`);
    messageCount += 1;
    message.ack();

  };

Comment: subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
   let t = setTimeout(() => {
    subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
    console.log(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`);
    return Responder.success(
                res,
                console.debug(
                    `request Timed out for ${subscriptionName}.`
                )
            )
  }, timeout * 1000);
}
listenForMessages();

Comment: Above is the code in sequence.